# caman js and image editing

Tags: javascript, camanjs

I want to create using caman js. I like the example on their page [here](http://camanjs.com/examples/). I tried to start my own, very simple one like this

```
window.onload =function(){
    var brightness = document.getElementById('brightness');
    var caman = Caman("#myimage");
    brightness.oninput = function(){
        caman.revert(false);
        caman.brightness(this.value);
        caman.render();
    };
};
```

The code above works as it should(changing the brightness) but it has two problems. First it has some glitches when reverting the image (although parameter is false) and second it lags when moving the slider because of render function. How can i make render not glitching the movement of the bar. It is so smooth in their example. I tried to read the code but i don't know why developers use f g h as their variable names :). I am at a begginer stage of jscript. Why is this lag happening?

Comment: Try listening for `onchange` instead of `oninput`. That can help about the lag.

Comment: Yes it does a bit, but I still get that flicker when caman is reverting. The example on their page uses onchange though too.